# Slack sending multiple messages to the Slack channel using slack api

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to send the multiple bot replies  to the same channel. using this API method: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage
But when i am sending multiple messages, The order in which the messages get rendered is not in the correct order, is there anyway to fix this.

Comment: Hi. could you please add more detail to your question? What to you mean by "correct". Also please add the relevant part of your code to the question.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken i am not getting the messages in the sequential order  How i pushed to slack, for ex 1st msg: Hello,   2nd msg: How may I help you, But in slack the messages is rendering as How may I help you, Hello, I'm pushing the messages to slack using chat.postMessage API, this will not happen always, it happens 10 out of 2 times.

Comment: Its likely the issue is in your code. Please add it to your question so that people can take a look.

Comment: @Jeevan Could you post some details of your code? like ErikKalkoken suggested?